# JQuery-UI datepicker not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, datepicker

I am trying to use the JQuery UI date picker but it only displays as a normal textbox. When I open the Google Chrome debugger there is one error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

This is my Bundle.config file

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace ultimateorganiser
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery - ui.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            //JQuery bxSlider
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/slider").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.bxslider.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery - ui.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view with the script code at the bottom

```
@model ultimateorganiser.Models.ClubMember
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   //UserDob
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserDoB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserDoB, new { id = "userdob" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserDoB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This should be retagged as a .Net MVC, Razor type issue. You're missing jquery UI dependencies. It would make this post more likely to come up for people with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in your view.

Comment: Yeah, the bundle looks like it's missing. The external reference to jquery is there, but the .datepicker function is missing because jquery UI isn't inlcuded.

Comment: Yeah, like says @Mic, you haven't add the bundle with jquery ui inside. Don't forget to remove the JQuery CDN put before and check that spaces present in your sample code aren't in your real code too ;-)